# UrlHelper.IsLocalUrl method always returns "false" for non-ASCII strings

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I recently detected, that `UrlHelper.IsLocalUrl` method always returns **`false`**, if it detects non-ASCII characters in the `url` parameter.

Example:

```
var isLocal = UrlHelper.IsLocalUrl("контакты"); //false
```

Is it a bug, or "by design"?

Comment: The method ought to be called `IsLocalPath` really, as the scheme and host is ignored.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The latest available implementation is checking for those conditions:

- the url starts with `"/"` and is not followed by `"/"` or `"\"`
- or the url starts with `"~"` and is followed by `"/"`

Thus all the urls passed to this method must start with `"/"` or `"~/"`.

Also, in case you wonder, it doesn't take the current host into account and check for schemes like `http` for instance.

**Update:**
Here is a link to the implementation which is used by `UrlHelper.IsLocalUrl`
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/600963a4df15#src/System.Web.WebPages/RequestExtensions.cs

Comment: Hi Sebastian! It seems that you are talking about Orchard CMS, when this question is related to ASP.NET MVC in general :) I saw that you've added a custom implementation of the `IsLocalUrl` in Orchard recently, but I didn't have a time to test it yet. Will try to provide a feedback asap. Thanks!

Comment: I am not talking about Orchard, but MVC 4 itself. Because of the MVC behavior we did implement a custom one as you noticed.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, because it better reflects current state.

Comment: For those who are interested: The behaviour has changed since MVC 3. In MVC 3 the current host was taken into place and now it is not anymore, unfortunately. This was a breaking change.

Comment: The link is not working, is this a problem with CodePlex?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because the URL in RFC is defined by the US-ASCII code set, with reserved characters.
You can read about URL specification here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

And a quote from the above site/document:

> URLs are written only with the graphic printable characters of the
>      US-ASCII coded character set. The octets 80-FF hexadecimal are not
>      used in US-ASCII, and the octets 00-1F and 7F hexadecimal represent
>      control characters; these must be encoded.

So in short, my guess is "by design".

Note: RFC is set by the IETF, which sets the standards of some technologies such as URL.

Comment: Yes, it seems that ASP.NET MVC`s `UrlHelper.IsLocalUrl` implementation strictly follows RFC 1738. To be honest, I don't understand why they do strictly follow almost 20-years old standard. The internet evolves, and it needs to be taken into consideration, if ASP.NET MVC still wants to be called "a modern web framework".